How to generate the contents of a "file" on demand for every read operation in Linux?
I have a CSV file that has a list of entries with known values, such as:
2024-11-01,78.5
2024-11-04,80.0
2024-11-06,78.0

There is a service, where I would like to upload this information to, but it expects a value for every date, so I need to interpolate to estimate the missing entries:
2024-11-01,78.5
2024-11-02,79.0
2024-11-03,79.5
2024-11-04,80.0
2024-11-05,79.0
2024-11-06,78.0

I will have to do this upload regularly each time after new data points get added. Is there a way to create a fake file on my filesystem that I can select from the browser upload dialog, which generates the fresh interpolated content from the source file each time it is accessed? So far the only seemingly proper approach I have found would be writing a custom FUSE driver that serves dynamic content, but that seems like an overkill solution to such a simple problem. As a workaround I have considered experimenting with inotify to replace the contents of the file each time the source gets written to, but that would require ensuring that this background service is running at all times. Is there a simpler method that I'm missing, like for example a special kind of symlink or FIFO that can trigger a process on each read and forward its output?
P.S. Feel free to move this over to StackOverflow if that seems more appropriate!

In essence this is a duplicate of Interpreted-on-read (ala php) for local files. I'm not voting to close your question because it seems you're asking for something simpler than what my answer there mentions. Besides, the answer, although upvoted, points to solutions without testing them and they may (or may not) be obsolete now. Anyway, at least linking the two questions together is the right thing and this very comment will do. Note the fact I'm not voting to close your question now does not mean others (or even myself) will not do this later.

I am not sure "simpler method" is well defined here, in that writing some code, to post to the remote website (instead of using a browser) would seem like a reasonable option, alternatively ensuring a process auto starts when the OS boots is also fairly simple - hence I don't see the problem with the inotify suggestion outlined in the question.

@KamilMaciorowski Thanks for the comment, ScriptFS looks exactly like what I'm looking for! Sadly it doesn't seem to be readily packaged for most distros, but I might try looking into it anyway. Regarding the similarity of the questions: I didn't manage to find the other one with the keywords I was using before, so I think that even if just as a redirect, this could stay up. Do you think that I should mark it as a duplicate and close it in order to forward all further traffic / discussion to the other one?

@DavidT Yes, if this was something that I were to do professionally, automating the whole procedure would make way more sense, but as it's just a small individual project, I decided that I'd rather learn something new and possibly useful later on than figure out the entire authentication and interaction stack of another site. :D
